# Replace words in file using sed command

Tags: sed

I have a file z. I want to replace string in File using sed command:

```
123: ' ',
```

to:

```
123: '456',
```

Comment: What is your goal? Are there many strings exactly equal to `123:''` in your file? Do you want to rewrite them `123:'456'`? Are you looking for something a bit more general?

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed (but be warned about the caveats of `sed -i` -- it recreates the file, breaking symlinks, although some newer versions of can mitigate that with `--follow-symlinks`):

```
sed -i "s/\b123: ' ',/123: '456',/g" z
```

Comment: I tried but command doesnt work....

Comment: Try `sed -i "s/123:'',/123:'456',/g" /path/to/file`

Comment: It works fine...but i have lots of single quote ' ' and i just want to put 456 to particular string which i have mentioned above.

Comment: @Chirag64 There is a space between the single quotes in the question.

Comment: @user66037 You're going to have to explain what you want more clearly, this works fine for me.

Comment: i have mentioned '' this many times in my file when i ran command given by you put 456 on all the single quote like  source: '456'
                prefix: '456',            
                    'apos;': '\'456',
            123: '456',
and i want 456 to be put on only 123: '',

Comment: `\b` is not POSIX

Comment: @user66037: mine won't work because I couldn't see the spaces between the characters. Chris Down's answer should work for your scenario though, it does work at my end.

Comment: Yeah it worked for me thank you Guys....Really Appreciate your kind response.

Comment: @user66037, if this answer solves your issue please take a minute and check the check mark under the vote count to the left, this will [signify to everyone]((http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that your issue's been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Using back referencing in `sed`,

```
$ echo "123: ' '," | sed "s/\(.*'\) \(.*\)/\1456\2/g"
123: '456',
```